# "Undefined offset: 1" error in Laravel. What is going on?

Tags: laravel

I´m trying to pass in my view all posts I have in my database with a foreach, but this error pops up.

Here is my view:

```
<ul>
  {{ <li>@foreach ($posts => $posts) }}
    <div class="row section scrollspy" style="padding:10px; margin-top:10px;">
      <div class="content-box col s12" style="padding:20px; margin-top:40px; background: #f2f2f2; border-radius:10px;">
        <div class="i_title" style="text-align:center; margin: -57px 0 0 0;">
          <a href="/profile" class="tooltip"><img class="responsive-img circle" src="images/profile_picture.jpg" style="width:60px; box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);"><span class="tooltiptext">@Username{{ $user->username }}</span></a>
        </div>
          <p class="col s12"{{ $post->post }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  {{ @endforeach</li> }}
</ul>
```

My Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UserController extends Controller
{
  public function getUsers()
  {
    $user = DB::table('users')->get();
    return view('layouts/welcomeView', ['users' => $user]);
  }
  public function getPosts()
  {
    $posts = DB::table('posts')->get();
    return view('layouts/welcomeView', ['posts' => $posts]);
  }
}
```

My database have some posts, so thats not the problem. I think that the trouble is that I´m not passing well the variable with the posts. What can I do??

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things wrong with this.

Firstly, you're mixing blade directives up. `{{ }}` is used to echo something out. Whatever is inside `{{` and `}}` is interpreted as PHP and is passed into a function to do some escaping and it is echoed out. So when you're doing `{{ <li>@foreach ($posts => $posts) }}`, the Blade compiler tries to treat `<li>@foreach ($posts => $posts)` as PHP code which will result in a syntax error. The `@foreach` doesn't belong inside `{{ }}`.

Secondly, I noticed inside your `@foreach` that you have `$posts => $posts`. Notice that the variables on each side of the arrow is the same? That is no doubt a typo but it would result in the first iteration of the loop overwriting the `$posts` variable with the first entry and the loop would try to continue iterating over this new, single value. It's likely that this is causing the error you're seeing.

This is probably closer to what you're looking for:

```
<ul>
  @foreach ($posts => $post)
    <li>
      <div class="row section scrollspy" style="padding:10px; margin-top:10px;">
        <div class="content-box col s12" style="padding:20px; margin-top:40px; background: #f2f2f2; border-radius:10px;">
          <div class="i_title" style="text-align:center; margin: -57px 0 0 0;">
            <a href="/profile" class="tooltip"><img class="responsive-img circle" src="images/profile_picture.jpg" style="width:60px; box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);"><span class="tooltiptext">@Username{{ $user->username }}</span></a>
          </div>
            <p class="col s12"{{ $post->post }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your view to;

```
<ul>
   <li> 
   @foreach ($posts => $post)
    <div class="row section scrollspy" style="padding:10px; margin-top:10px;">
      <div class="content-box col s12" style="padding:20px; margin-top:40px; background: #f2f2f2; border-radius:10px;">
        <div class="i_title" style="text-align:center; margin: -57px 0 0 0;">
          <a href="/profile" class="tooltip"><img class="responsive-img circle" src="images/profile_picture.jpg" style="width:60px; box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);"><span class="tooltiptext">@Username{{ $user->username }}</span></a>
        </div>
          <p class="col s12"{{ $post->post }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
  </li>
</ul>
```

You might need to move `@Username` if that isn't defined somewhere.

It is generally good practice to check there is something in an array before you foreach it.

You can achieve this by doing;

```
@if(! $posts->isEmpty()) 
    @foreach ($posts => $post)
        ....
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: @Metalhead Also, it's common to have if check outside `<ul>` and foreach outside `<li>`.